# Javascript Jasmine test success not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I'm having a weird issue where when there are errors the test fails. Tells me there is 1 spec that ran and 1 failed.

```
1 spec, 1 failure in 0.069s
```

Now when I go and write code to make it pass the site goes green and says 0 specs 0 failure.

```
0 specs, 0 failures in 0.001s
```

I'm following hte mstwjs first book. My gemfile looks like this

```
group :test, :development do
   #gem 'guard-rails-assets'
   #gem 'guard-jasmine-headless-webkit'
   gem 'jasmine-headless-webkit'
   gem 'jasmine'
   gem 'jasminerice'
   gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

My toggler.js file

```
  1 function init() {
  2   var $toggleLinks = $(".detail_toggle");
  1   $toggleLinks.click(function(event) {
  2     var $detail = $(this).siblings(".detail");
  3     $detail.toggleClass("hidden");
  4     event.preventDefault();
  5   };
  6 }
  7 
  8 $(function() {
  9   init();
 10 });
```

My toggler spec

```
  6 describe("Trip detail toggler", function() {
  5   describe("clicking a show link", function() {
  4     it("shows the trip description", function() {
  3       loadFixtures("one_index_trip.html");
  2       init();
  1       $(".detail_toggle").click();
  7         expect($('.detail')).not.toHaveClass("hidden");
  1     });
  2   });
  3 });
```

Comment: Have you tried: $(".detail_toggle").trigger("click");

Comment: @zvona That doesn't solve it. Still no change in the spec.